# sort order with space characters

Tags: bash, python-2.7, sorting, awk

I have a `TSV` file containing chemical names, which can contain parentheses, commas, + and - signs, space characters, [], {}, etc.:

```
$ cat random.txt 
ACETYLTHIOCHOLINE CHLORIDE  CDRD-00117030-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHANAMIDE   CDRD-00118894-01
ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID CDRD-00119007-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN    CDRD-00117996-01
ACETYL ISOALLOGAMBOGIC ACID CDRD-00118740-01
ACETAMINOPHEN   CDRD-00116365-01
ACETAMIDE   CDRD-00116997-01
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID    CDRD-00117028-01
ACETYLSALICYLSALICYLIC ACID CDRD-00115640-01
ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER CDRD-00118256-01
```

What I want is a file sorted one the first column:

```
$ cat correct.txt 
ACETAMIDE       CDRD-00116997-01
ACETAMINOPHEN       CDRD-00116365-01
ACETYL ISOALLOGAMBOGIC ACID     CDRD-00118740-01
ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID     CDRD-00119007-01
ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER     CDRD-00118256-01
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID        CDRD-00117028-01
ACETYLSALICYLSALICYLIC ACID     CDRD-00115640-01
ACETYLTHIOCHOLINE CHLORIDE      CDRD-00117030-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN    CDRD-00117996-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHANAMIDE   CDRD-00118894-01
```

What I get:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -t $'\t' -f -n random.txt > wrong.txt
$ cat wrong.txt          
ACETAMIDE   CDRD-00116997-01
ACETAMINOPHEN    CDRD-00116365-01
ACETYL ISOALLOGAMBOGIC ACID     CDRD-00118740-01
ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID  CDRD-00119007-01
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID     CDRD-00117028-01
ACETYLSALICYLSALICYLIC ACID  CDRD-00115640-01
ACETYLTHIOCHOLINE CHLORIDE   CDRD-00117030-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHANAMIDE    CDRD-00118894-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN    CDRD-00117996-01
ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER  CDRD-00118256-01
```

Note that `ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER` should be **after** `ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID`, whereas `ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN` should be **before** `ACETYLTRYPTOPHANAMIDE`.

The reason is that `join` complains about `ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER` not being sorted (and about `ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN` once the first has been fixed):

Second file for `join`:

```
$ cat test_data.txt
Acetamide   0.904   0.146   0.134   -0.196
Acetyltryptophan    -0.558  -0.471  -0.13   -0.332
```

Results of `join` with `wrong.txt`:

```
$ join -a1 -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t' -i test_data.txt wrong.txt 
Acetamide   0.904   0.146   0.134   -0.196  CDRD-00116997-01
Acetyltryptophan    -0.558  -0.471  -0.13   -0.332
join: wrong.txt:9: is not sorted: ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN  CDRD-00117996-01
```

Of course, `join` with `correct.txt` works:

```
$ join -a1 -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t' -i test_data.txt correct.txt
Acetamide   0.904   0.146   0.134   -0.196  CDRD-00116997-01
Acetyltryptophan    -0.558  -0.471  -0.13   -0.332  CDRD-00117996-01
```

This `sort` call doesn't give me the desired output either:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -t $'\t' -f -V random.txt 
ACETAMIDE   CDRD-00116997-01
ACETAMINOPHEN   CDRD-00116365-01
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID    CDRD-00117028-01
ACETYLSALICYLSALICYLIC ACID CDRD-00115640-01
ACETYLTHIOCHOLINE CHLORIDE  CDRD-00117030-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN    CDRD-00117996-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHANAMIDE   CDRD-00118894-01
ACETYL ISOALLOGAMBOGIC ACID CDRD-00118740-01
ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID CDRD-00119007-01
ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER CDRD-00118256-01
```

How do I get `sort` to output what I want?

Comment: your correct.txt is generated by `sort random.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably your locale that is messing the sort. Try:

```
LANG=C sort -k1,1 -t $'\t' -f random.txt
```

Credits:
https://superuser.com/questions/625223/sort-tab-delimited-text-fields-involving-spaces

Comment: I marked this answer as correct even though @BinaryZebra's answer is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the -n (numeric sort) and it should work:

```
sort -k1,1 -t $'\t' random.txt
```

Of course, that's assuming the locale you are using has the sort order you need. You may change it to test ( if needed and the locale has been compiled in your system)

```
LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8
```

In which country/language are you working?

This work correctly:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort -k1,1 -t $'\t' random.txt
```